# How To Change SQL Query

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, date

**How can I modify this query to >>> @Date1 is a date (date only no time)**

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP (200) dbo.tb_ShowTime.VenueId, DATEADD(Hour, DATEDIFF(Hour, 0, dbo.tb_ShowTime.StartDateTime), 0) AS StartDateTime
FROM         tb_ShowTime
WHERE     (dbo.tb_ShowTime.IsDeleted = 0) AND (dbo.tb_ShowTime.StartDateTime BETWEEN @Date1 AND @Date2)
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT TOP (200) dbo.tb_EventSectionTime.VenueId, DATEADD(Hour, DATEDIFF(Hour, 0, dbo.tb_EventSectionTime.EventTime), 0) AS StartDateTime
FROM         tb_EventSectionTime
WHERE     (dbo.tb_EventSectionTime.IsDeleted = 0) AND (dbo.tb_EventSectionTime.EventTime BETWEEN @Date1 AND @Date2)
ORDER BY StartDateTime
```

Comment: FYI: DISTINCT with UNION is superfluous because UNION removes duplicates. Also, the TOP 200 in each is a random 200 rows. You'd need a derived table to read TOP 200..ORDER BY... before the UNION and the outer ORDER BY

Comment: What do you mean? A simple `EventTime> @Date1`? What does >>> mean in your question?

Comment: I read it that the OP needs to change the query so that @Date1 is a date excluding the time, assuming that its currently a `datetime`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure which dbms you're using, but in Sybase you can convert to string then back to datetime, to lose time portion. Sure you can do something similar with others.

```
convert(datetime,convert(varchar,@Date1,109))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use these functions
`Day(@date1)` return day of the date
`Month(@date1)` return month of the date
`year(@date1)`return year of the date

Answer (score 0):

When I came accross this problem I used `CAST(@Date1 as DATE)` That is in SQL-Server. It truncates time piece to 00:00:00. 
If you are using a different DBMS try to find casting function for the relevant engine.

Comment: Just to add that this datatype was added in SQL Server 2008, so won't work in previous versions.

Comment: We've been told "@Date1 is a date (date only no time)" already.